# Xen Live Migration with Gluster

Tags: xen, high-availability, virtual-machines

Has anyone used or found a HOWTO on how to use Xen with Gluster? I'm working on a testbed of two servers, possibly three, that will be syncing a volume via IP and I'd like to work on finding a way to do live migration of the VM between (among) the servers but I don't see any howtos for setting that up or managing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know a couple people who run [DRDB](http://www.drbd.org/). What that does is mirror each fs operation. Then move the IPs with [heartbeat](http://www.linux-ha.org/Heartbeat) around and you got migration. Not sure if it's as robust as ESX' hot migration.

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is now over a year old...

for the record: there is a posting about this on the opensharedroot.org list.

dom0 using shared root on gluster.